# R generalized hyperbolic distribution plot line in hist

Tags: r, plot, line, distribution

I have the following code:

```
x.grid <- seq(-0.05,to=0.05,by=0.001)
hist(df$dataset.d.return.aex, breaks=100, main='daily returns')
```

Which results in the following plot:
[[image: hist1]

Now, I want to draw the implied marginal distributions in histograms of the daily returns, where I use a generalized hyperbolic distribution. I tried to do it with the following code:

```
ghypuv <- fit.ghypuv(data = returns[,"d.return.aex"], symmetric = TRUE)
lines(ghypuv, col="blue")
```

However, this results in the following plot:
[image: hist+line]

So, my question is, how to properly draw the implied marginal distributions (using a generalized hyperbolic distribution) in histograms of the daily returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `hist(..., freq=FALSE)` to use density rather than number of counts on the y-axis.

(This is probably a duplicate ...)